# Reading each column data of row from csv file and apply a formula based on column index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I have a soil sample in a CSV file

```
        pH    K      Zn      Fe  Cu     Mn
Soil 1  7.74 279    0.48    6.4 0.21    4.7
Soil 2  9.02 247    0.27    6.4 0.16    5.6
Soil 3  7.8  265    0.46    6.2 0.51    6.1
Soil 4  8.36 127    0.5     3.1 0.28    2.3
```

I need to read each soil sample and for each element, I need to add a particular formula to check whether the soil is low fertile, non-fertile, or fertile.

My concept is to convert the CSV to list and then from the received 2D list, I can iterate through each element of the row and check the parameter for each of the nutrients.

I used the following code:

```
    import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

with open('datan.csv', newline='') as soil_file: #CSV datafile
    soil_reader = csv.reader(soil_file)
    data = list(soil_reader)
    data.pop(0) #first row is string
    for i in data:
        for j in i: #iterate through each element of the row
            if((float(j) >= 5.1 and float(j) <= 6.5) or (float(j) >= 7.6 and float(j) <= 8.5)):
                print("Soil is low fertile")  #condition
            elif((float(j) < 5) or (float(j) > 8.5)):
                print("Soil is Non fertile")
            else:
                print("Soil is fertile")
```

The issue is, the loop starts from the first element and goes up to the end of the last row, without stopping at the end of the row, and the condition is true in all cases. So I get all the 24 elements result.

What I need is that the loop should check the first soil sample and print the result and then move onto the next soil sample.

I don't know how to implement pandas here but have read somewhere that through Dataframe I can read index by using:

```
df.index
```

but that reads the whole column rather than the row!
What I need is somewhat like:

```
for Soil 1:
if df[index] == 'ph':
Use func pH()
elif df[index] == 'K':
Use func K()
```

and so on...

P.S. I made a silly mistake of not adding a counter to the loop

I've made some changes in the code and now the loop stops after reading the first element but doesn't check other conditions inside the function.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


def pH(j):
    if ((float(j) >= 5.1 and float(j) <= 6.5) or (float(j) >= 7.6 and float(j) <= 8.5)):
        print("Soil is low fertile")

        def pH(j):
            if ((float(j) >= 5.1 and float(j) <= 6.5) or (float(j) >= 7.6 and float(j) <= 8.5)):
                print("Soil is low fertile")
                return
            elif ((float(j) < 5) or (float(j) > 8.5)):
                print("Soil is Non fertile")
                return
            else:
                print("Soil is fertile")
                return
    elif ((float(j) < 5) or (float(j) > 8.5)):
        print("Soil is Non fertile")
        return
    else:
        print("Soil is fertile")
        return

with open('datan.csv', newline='') as soil_file:
    soil_reader = csv.reader(soil_file)
    data = list(soil_reader)
    data.pop(0)
    #print(data, end="\n")
    n=0
    for i in data:
        for j in i:
            n=n+1
            if n==1:
                pH(j)
            continue
```

Thanks!

Comment: In this case your index is Soil 1, Soil 2 etc.  If you want the column names you would use df.columns.  Also, with pandas a vectorized approach would be much faster than iteration.  See pandas apply()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your columns directly with df['pH'] or df.pH (if column names do not have space or special chars)

Are you okay with having another column that would represent the fertility or do you want the print statements necessarily(wanted to ask in comments but don't have enough reputation)

For another column for representing fertility,you can use loc and pass your filter

`df.loc[df.ph>=5.1,"fertility"] = "fertile"`

For looping through your columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
  # displaying 
  display(df.loc[df[col]>6])
```

If you only have multiple outputs and formula for each, you can use :

```
filter_criteria = {"fertile":(df.pH>8)&(df.K<200),"non-fertile":(df.pH>7.5)&(df.K>240),"low":(df.pH>7.5)&(df.K>270)}
for key in filter_criteria.keys():
 df.loc[filter_criteria[key],"fertility"] = key
```

Comment: Yes, I need to add a column at last which shows the fertility of the soil, and should I add all column indexes as filter_threshhold?

Comment: And if I check the column index using df['pH'] then how I can use multiple formulas based on conditions for fertile, low fertile, and non-fertile?
Thanks!

Comment: so you only require multiple outputs ? and these formulas are to be applied on all columns?

Comment: Yes every nutrients has a different range to differentiate themselves from being non-fertile or low fertile, so I needed to apply formulas on all columns and each should return an output. I've crossed the first hurdle of checking each element with its range by using if-elif case and calling appropriate function when the counter reaches the column index. I'm now stuck at getting all those values from function to a new CSV in the same format as above. I'm a beginner in programming.

Comment: okay..i've added that to the answer as well ...you can mention the range in the filter criteria like : (df.pH>0.5)&(df.K>200)&(df.K<400) etc

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer due to my reputation limit :(
But Thanks a lot, it did the work!!!

Comment: @SandarbhAsthana you would probably have the option to accept the answer.There should be a tick under the vote option